# How do i add vite.config.js file to my project?

Tags: npm, build, tailwind-css, vite

I added vite to my project to run TailwindCSS. And now I am done and I wanted to build the project. But it only builds my index.html, not all my other pages (just using vanilla html and js). I know the line "npx tailwindcss init -p" to add the tailwind.config.js. Is there a command like this for Vite so i can say to build ./*.html?

```
 {
  "name": "tirisi",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "serve": "npm run build && vite preview"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
    "postcss": "^8.4.8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.23",
    "vite": "^2.8.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/line-clamp": "^0.3.1",
    "daisyui": "^2.11.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://vitejs.dev/config/

> The most basic config file looks like this:
>
> ```js
> // vite.config.js
> export default {
>   // config options
> }
> ```

Just create that file and paste that in. There's no vite equiv to `npm init` or `tailwind init`

Comment: Ahh ok, do you know the syntax to tell to build all ./*.html files?

Comment: I would expect it to do so automatically - is that not happening for you?

Comment: No.. i've also tried to put them all the html pages in a public file. It builds my ./images, ./script.js and ./index.html, but not all my other pages.